# Why double becomes int?

Tags: c#, integer, double

When I run this code, I get output "System.Double, 3"

```
namespace NewApp 
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double a = 1.0;
            double b = 2.7;
            a = Math.Round(b);
            Console.WriteLine(a.GetType() + ", " + a);
        }

    }
}
```

**Why I see "3", if `a` is double variable and I supposed to see "3.0"?**

Comment: It says "System.Double" in the output. What's the problem?

Comment: Rounds a double-precision floating-point value to the nearest integral value, and rounds midpoint values to the nearest even number.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ yes, but Math.Round() returned double value, however I see integer value - "3"

Comment: No, you see a double value with no decimal point. You didn't say how to format it, so it formatted it minimally.

Comment: @madreflection why I see "3" if 3 - is integer?

Comment: It's a string representation. You need to specify the format if you need to see decimal places that are not significant.

Comment: And what you're seeing is not an integer, it's a string.

Comment: @madreflection why it isn`t output "3.0"?

Comment: WriteLine decided not to write the .0. If you think about it, it makes sense: it's easier to read 2.7 than 2.70000000000000000000000. If you specifically want it see the .0, you can specify how you want it formatted! :)

Comment: Technically, `String.Concat` called `ToString` on `a`, and `Double.ToString` decided not to write the ".0".

Comment: Why you expect 3.0 at all and not 3.00? You tell the console to output a number and the console wants to save resources by not wasting place with unnecessary decimal places.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thx! Your answer turned out to be the most understandable :)

Comment: @НикитаПопов: You can always force a specific format when you output a number as string, for example: `Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(2.7).ToString("N1"))` which outputs `3.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is still double. You are facing with 3 instead of 3.0 because of the way Console.write  works. Use this as example

```
Console.WriteLine(DoubleConverter.ToExactString(a))
```

Comment: Nothing to do with `Console.WriteLine` and everything to do with `double.ToString`, which `string.Concat` calls (via the `+` operator), the result is then fed to `WriteLine`

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are saying `a` is `Math.Round(b);`

Meaning `a` will be **3**

```
double a = 1.0; // a -> 1.0
double b = 2.7; // b -> 2.7
a = Math.Round(b); // a = 2.7 "rounded up" -> a = 3
Console.WriteLine(a.GetType() + ", " + a); // a is a double and 
// the value is 3 (check previous line)
```

Edit:

About the decimals, if you round up, you get no decimals, so its **3** instead of **3.0** I believe

```
Math.Round(); returns a value with no decimals
```

Comment: `Math.Round` does *not* return an int

Comment: How I see in docs, Math.Round() returns double

Comment: @DavidG doesnt it? "Round a number to an integer by using the rounding-to-nearest convention." taken from the Microsoft Docs.

Comment: Per the [Microsoft documentation on Math.Round()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-6.0#system-math-round(system-double)), passing a double into Math.Round() will return a double, not an int.

Comment: "Round a number to an integer by using the rounding-to-nearest convention." Round(Decimal) -or- Round(Double) 
takem from Microsoft Docs [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @AcisSys [Read those docs again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wizAr.png), note how it says "Returns ... Double". It returns the integer component of a number, but it's still a double.

Comment: @DavidG the variable is still a double, but it returns a value with no decimals, thats what i meant with "returns an Int"

Comment: Then say that properly. Your answer literally says "returns an int", how can anybody ever take that in a different way?